# Custom OpenLayers Design

Tags: user-interface, controls, zooming, openlayers

I want to change the default UI for OpenLayers (Zoom bar, direction...) using my own images, which have different sizes then the original ones.
The problem however, remains in the positioning and the dimensions of the elements which is hard coded in javascript.

Could anyone tell me how to use my own mock-up for the different controls or at least give some ideas ?

Comment: Modification of those hard-coded values seems to be onliest solution.

Comment: well it is opensource, so it should be posible, also nobody said you have to use the standard zoom bar and other standard controls. You can create your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenLayers, you can subclass any control, to really make it whatever you'd like.  I've taken the liberty to subclass the PanZoomBar per your question to make it look more like a Google Maps PanZoomBar.  First, create your control:

```
var panZoomBar = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
    panIcons: false // my custom option I use to hide the pan buttons
});
```

Next, override the control with methods you'd like to customize.  For this example, I'll be overriding the `draw()` function in order to add my own css styles, images, and positioning:

```
OpenLayers.Util.extend(panZoomBar, {
    draw: function(px) {
        // initialize our internal div
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
        px = this.position.clone();

        // place the controls
        this.buttons = [];

        var sz = {w: 18, h: 18};
        if (this.panIcons) { // will only draw our pan tools if this option is configured
            var centered = new OpenLayers.Pixel(px.x+sz.w/2, px.y);
            var wposition = sz.w;

            if (this.zoomWorldIcon) {
                centered = new OpenLayers.Pixel(px.x+sz.w, px.y);
            }

            this._addButton("panup", "north-mini.png", centered, sz);
            px.y = centered.y+sz.h;
            this._addButton("panleft", "west-mini.png", px, sz);
            if (this.zoomWorldIcon) {
                this._addButton("zoomworld", "zoom-world-mini.png", px.add(sz.w, 0), sz);

                wposition *= 2;
            }
            this._addButton("panright", "east-mini.png", px.add(wposition, 0), sz);
            this._addButton("pandown", "south-mini.png", centered.add(0, sz.h*2), sz);
            this._addButton("zoomin", "gmaps-zoom-plus-mini.png", centered.add(0, sz.h*3+5), sz);
            centered = this._addZoomBar(centered.add(0, sz.h*4 + 5));
            this._addButton("zoomout", "gmaps-zoom-minus-mini.png", centered, sz);
        }
        else {
            this._addButton("zoomin", "gmaps-zoom-plus-mini.png", px, sz);
            centered = this._addZoomBar(px.add(0, sz.h));
            this._addButton("zoomout", "gmaps-zoom-minus-mini.png", centered, sz);
            if (this.zoomWorldIcon) {
                centered = centered.add(0, sz.h+3);
                this._addButton("zoomworld", "zoom-world-mini.png", centered, sz);
            }
        }
        // add custom CSS styles
        $(this.slider).find('img').attr('src', media_url + 'OpenLayers-2.12/img/gmaps-slider.png');
        $(this.zoombarDiv).css('background-image', 'url("' + media_url + 'OpenLayers-2.12/img/gmaps-zoombar.png")');
        return this.div;
    }
});
```

Then simply add this control to the map:

```
map.addControl(panZoomBar);
```